Domain of quotient of quadratics with one common root
Consider a function $$f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 3 x + 2}{x^2 - 4 x + 3}.$$
What is the value of the function at $x = 1$ ?
If we substitute directly, we get an indeterminate form, and thus $f(1)$ is undefined.
but we can also simply factorize it, and cancel out the common term, i.e. $(x-1)$. This gives us $f(1)=\dfrac{1}{2}$.
What is the correct answer and why?

Canceling a common factor is not permitted when this common factor equals $~0.$

This is a common point of confusion but you can make sense of it by asking yourself what cancelling out the common terms does. Writing it out gives:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2-4x+3}=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x-3)(x-1)}$$
When $f$ is evaluated at 1, we have a "$\frac{0}{0}$" situation due to $x-1$ terms. The reason why this doesn't work is because, when cancelling the $x-1$ terms, you're essentially dividing the numerator and denominator by the common term $x-1$. But this assumes that $x-1\neq 0$ or $x\neq 1$ since otherwise the operation is not well defined, which is not the case when $f$ is evaluated at $1$.

It is given that
$$f(x)=\frac{x^{2}-3x+2}{x^{2}-4x+3}$$
Now you can find the domain by following this method.
According to your point @Shreyas, I would like to explain you when you can cancel $(x-1)$ in both the numerator and the denominator.
$f(x)=\frac{x^{2}-3x+2}{x^{2}-4x+3}$
$\implies f(x)=\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{(x-1)(x-3)}$
Clearly you can cancel $(x-1)$ in both the numerator and the denominator when $(x-1)\neq 0$.
That is $(x-1)\neq 0$ $\implies x\neq 1$
Again, when $x\neq 1$ then you will likely cancel $(x-1)$ in both the numerator and denominator.
Therefore $$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-3}$$
Now observe carefully.
If $$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-3}$$ then $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=3$.
Therefore we should also note that $(x-3)\neq 0$ which implies $x\neq 3$.
Therefore finally you get the domain of $f(x)$ to be as
$f(x)\in (-\infty,\infty)\setminus${$1,3$}
Note :
The Numerator can be $0$ for $x=2$ but the denominator can't be $0$ for $x=1$ because then $f(x)$ will be undefined.

As you have written it, $f(x)$ is indeed undefined at $x=1.$ We say that $f$ has a discontinuity at $x-1.$ However, as you mentioned we can cancel an $x-1$ (or even take the limit as $x \to 1$) to see that, in a certain sense, $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}.$ We call this type of discontinuity a removeable discontinuity because $x=1$ is a point where the function is undefined, but the function can be redefined to make it analytic (smooth and differentiable). That is, we can define a new function $$g(x) := \begin{cases}f(x) \quad x \neq 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} \quad \quad \, x =1\end{cases}$$ Which is analytic at $x=1.$

Also a pole at $x = 3$.

You may have meant $x=1$ in the bottom case of your equation

$f(1)$ is undefined. But
$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Note that
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2-4x+3}$$
and
$$g(x)=\frac{x-2}{x-3}$$
are different functions, as they have different domains. So we can have that $f(1)$ is undefined but $g(1)=\frac{1}{2}$.
